# trying to figure out what kind of unicode should i have

Tags: java, .net, unicode, utf-8, ucs2

I'm working on spring boot on a project that fetch the data from the database then use post method to send them through HTTP post request, everything is okay but with Latina, the data i have in database encoded with: `ISO 8859-6` i have encoded it to `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` but still it returns unreadable text question marks and special characters

test example in Arabic :

`مرحبا`

should be like this to be valid and reliable after post method :

`06450631062d06280627`

i can't figure out what kind of encoding happend here, now im doing integration from `.NET` to `java`:

this what they used in `.NET` :

```
public static String UnicodeStr2HexStr(String strMessage)
        {
            byte[] ba = Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetBytes(strMessage);
            String strHex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
            strHex = strHex.Replace("-", "");
            return strHex;
        }
```

i just need to know what kind of encoding happend here to apply in java, and it would helpfull if someone provide me with way:

i have tried this but it return different value:

```
String encodedWithISO88591 = "مرحبا;
String decodedToUTF8 = new String(encodedWithISO88591.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: This is very confused. It looks like the .NET is converting a string to a hexadecimal representation of UTF-16be. In Java, you have a UTF-16be string which you convert to bytes with 8859-1, which will fail and mess up your data, which bytes you then convert back to a UTF-16be string using UTF-8 encoding. Also, you said the data is 8859-6 but nothing else about that appears anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking to get is the hex representation of the Arabic String in `UTF-16BE`

```
String yourVal = "مرحبا";
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(yourVal.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE)));
```

output will be :

```
06450631062D06280627
```